# How to implement expiring roles in Drupal 7 today?

Tags: 7, users

I am in the processing of making a membership site that requires some user roles to expire after a set period of time.

The most obvious choice would be the [role expire](http://drupal.org/project/role_expire) module but none of the 7.x releases have been updated in six months and the issue queue has some patches that have been marked as needing review for weeks.

[Commerce subscription](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_subscription) is another module under development that hasn't seen any action in about six months.

The only module I could find with a stable release is [Commerce subscription products](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_sp), which rather than being an independent module is actually a feature consisting of rules, commerce, and some fields (as per the module page).

As a site builder with a release coming in the next month or two, since it seems like there is no clear clean solution at the moment, would it be crazy to simply not implement any of these solutions and do something basic in rules myself, handling expirations manually for the first few months?  (Roles will expire monthly, and I don't anticipate more than 100 or so roles needing to be removed each month.)  Then, if use of the site started taking off, I could look at implementing one of these solutions again.  Or is there some good way to do role expiration today that I missed?

Comment: The fact that role expire hasn't had a release for 6 months isn't an issue. You should test it to see if it actually fits your needs. Disclaimer - I work a lot with Role Expire and have commit access.

Comment: You could use the rules and rules_scheduler module to implement your own solution.

Comment: I just tried Role Expire and the rules integration doesn't work on D7.12 with Rules 2.1.  There's a patch in the issue queue http://drupal.org/node/1370262#comment-5487138 but I wasn't able to apply it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [Commerce License](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_license) module that has a stable release and some support. I highly recommend it.

Comment: Role Expire has basically not been updated since the 2012 dev release in my first answer, so I'm switching my recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

As of the 2012-Apr-10 dev release, [Role Expire](http://drupal.org/project/role_expire) includes working rules integration in D7.  I am now using it successfully to meet my needs.